# Can I install laminate flooring over a toilet drain that has been eliminated?

Tags: basement

I had a toilet in my basement that I don't want anymore.  Whats the best way to seal it off and be able to install laminate floor over the top?

Comment: While _you_ may no longer want it there, you might want to strongly consider the access to it for future owners. Having the ability to add another bathroom could be a strong selling point, so any sort of "permanent" covering may not work in your long term favor.

Comment: You really need to provide more information. We don't know what kind of pipe you have. We don't know whether the pipe protrudes. Please provide a minimal level of detail (and photos if possible) so we can help properly.